# Difference between string literal and string in cout statement?

Tags: c++, cout, stdstring

What is the difference between the following ways of printing a string?

```
std::cout << "hello";

// and

std::cout << std::string("hello");
```

They both appear to do the same thing.

Comment: There's no difference actually. Check the assembly code emitted by the compiler.

Comment: You are missing `#include <string>` and you should rather use `(std::string)"hello"`

Comment: The second one has more letters than the first one.  The second one uses parentheses, and the first one has no parentheses.

Comment: the second one has 8 more characters. Also this code wont compile as thats an ilegal comment. Plus dont do `using namespace std` see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice

Comment: One invokes `operator<<` overload taking `const char*`, the other an overload taking `std::string`. Both calls will produce the same output.

Comment: I thought humanity was able to figure out that this is a question with an example, and not the actual code... I was wrong.

Comment: @Jeffrey `(std::string)"hello"` and `std::string("hello")` do exactly the same, only that the C-style cast form is often discouraged in C++.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ godbolt would disagree with you on that

Comment: This appears to be a clear question, and I'm not sure what additional details are required. I've cleaned it up slightly, if that helps. There doesn't appear to be a duplicate target for this question (or at least, I couldn't find one), so I'm voting to reopen.

Comment: @MaskOryle was your question answered by any of the answers or are there details missing that you'd like us to add?

Answer (score 1):

`std::cout << "hello";` uses the [`operator<<`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/operator_ltlt2) overload dealing with null terminated character arrays. `"hello"`, which is a `const char[6]`, *decay* s into a `const char*` when passed as an argument to the `operator<<` overload:

```cpp
template< class CharT, class Traits >
basic_ostream<CharT,Traits>& operator<<( basic_ostream<CharT,Traits>& os,
                                         const char* s );
```

`std::cout << std::string("hello");` uses the [`operator<<`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator_ltltgtgt) overload for dealing with strings. `std::string` is a `typedef` for `std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char>>`.

```cpp
template <class CharT, class Traits, class Allocator>
std::basic_ostream<CharT, Traits>&
    operator<<(std::basic_ostream<CharT, Traits>& os,
               const std::basic_string<CharT, Traits, Allocator>& str);
```

Answer (score 1):

##### Case 1

Here we consider the statement:

```
std::cout << "hello";
```

In the above statement `"hello"` is a **string literal** of type `const char[6]` which **decays** to a `const char*` due to **type decay**. This `const char*` is then passed to  the **non-member** overload of [`operator<<`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/operator_ltlt2) given below:

```
template< class CharT, class Traits >
basic_ostream<CharT,Traits>& operator<<( basic_ostream<CharT,Traits>& os,
                                         const char* s );
```

##### Case 2

Here we consider the statement:

```
std::cout << std::string("hello");
```

In the above statement the expression `std::string("hello")` creates a temporary `std::string` object. Now since the `std::string` has overloaded [`operator<<`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator_ltltgtgt)(given below), that overloaded version of `operator<<` will be called and its body will be executed.

```
template <class CharT, class Traits, class Allocator>
std::basic_ostream<CharT, Traits>&
    operator<<(std::basic_ostream<CharT, Traits>& os,
               const std::basic_string<CharT, Traits, Allocator>& str);
```